# How to use buttons in ASP.NET Core to call a method via onClick

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make a button in my View call a method in the Model using the button's onClick event, but I am not sure how to make this work. The button just doesn't do anything.

This is my View:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Coins: @Model.Coins</p>
        <button type="button" id="btnScore"
                onclick="Btn_Click">Click me!</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the model I try to call the method in:

```
public class ClickerGame

    {
        public int Coins { get; set; }

        public ClickerGame()
        {
            Coins = 0;
        }

        public void Btn_Click()
        {
            Coins++;
        }
}
```

This is the Controller:

```
public class ClickerController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ClickerGame model = new ClickerGame();
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

And this is my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Clicker}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

I am able to get the amount of coins in calling @Model.Coins in the View, but when I try to use @Model.Btn_Click it gives me an error saying the method can't be converted to a delegate object.
I am using Asp.Net Core 1.0.1 in visual studio.

**Edit:**
I changed the Controller and the View and it now is able to call the method, but when it tries to increase the coin variable I get a NullReference exception...

The View:

```
@model AspNetClicker.Models.ClickerGame

<script>
    function IncrementCount()
    {
        location.href = "@Url.Action("IncrementCount")";
    }
</script>


<html>

<body>
    <div>
        <p>Coins: @Model.Coins</p>
        <button type="button" id="btnScore"
                onclick="IncrementCount()">
            Click me!
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ClickerGame:

```
public class ClickerGame

    {
        public int Coins { get; set; }

        public ClickerGame()
        {
            Coins = 0;
        }
}
```

ClickerController:

```
public class ClickerController : Controller
{
    ClickerGame model;

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        model = new ClickerGame();
        return View(model);
    }

    public void IncrementCount()
    {
        model.Coins++;
    }
}
```

Comment: as far as I know onclick should have a javascript call. There are other ways to call a .NET method (like, callback, etc), but it can't be the way you have written. You may need to write a javascript method "Btn_Click". Regarding the error message, you need to put empty brackets just besides Btn_Click in onclick of your button HTML tag

Comment: You are not using any inbuilt template or ajax call ,how can they call click event....it is not .aspx ,it is mvc.

Comment: Probably you mixed aspnet webforms and mvc approachs. You can start to read official aspnet core docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview

Comment: you can't call a specific method of any old .NET class from Javascript. In the MVC flavour of ASP.NET, you must create an Action method within a Controller. Have your javascript make a request to the action (via a postback, or ajax, or just redirecting, depending on the use case) and then within the action method you can call any other .NET methods necessary in order to process the request correctly.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to do that like in Web Forms. Follow these steps to make it work in MVC:

**1. Change your View code to the below code:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Coins: @Model.Coins</p>
        <button type="button" id="btnScore"
                onclick="IncrementCount()">Click me!</button>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
function IncrementCount() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Clicker/IncrementCount",       
        async: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: function () {
            return "error";
        }
    });
}
</script>

</html>
```

**2. In your controller add an action method `IncrementCount` and increment the count here.**

```
public class ClickerController : Controller
{       
    [HttpPost]
    public void IncrementCount()
    {
        // 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented the code you gave me and it would make sense for me that it would work, but the debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoint I added to ClickerController.IncrementCount(). Do I perhaps need to edit my Mvc route as well?

Comment: It doesn't work for me even though I have it exactly as you put it in your answer. When I set a breakpoint on the Ajax code I get the warning the breakpoint will not be hit as well.

Comment: If you wait for sometime, I will test the solution and check if any issue is there at my side.

Comment: @ViVi instead of `url: "/ClickerController/IncrementCount"` it would be more robust to do `url: '@Url.Action("IncrementCount", "ClickerController")'` - this will ensure the correct URL is hit. Then any unusual routing config or hosting arrangements are accounted for by MVC when generating the URL. It could be in this example the breakpoint is not being hit because the URL is wrong for the OP's environment. OP should check the network tab for any HTTP errors (404 would be likely)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="nextUrl()"/>

 function nextUrl() {
    location.href = "/Home/Contact";
}
```

Comment: I tried something like this and edited my question to show my up to date code. This sadly gave me a different problem. :/