# Call a method from button click in ASP.net, using controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, button, controller

am new to ASP.net. Am trying to have a simple page view that has a button and when clicked, this would call a method that is in a controller, to then do more code and computation with c#.

I read posts and tried this but the method does not seem to be called, the debugger never stops in the Controler ClickButton1 method.

My VIEW code

```html
<div>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Button 1" onclick="ClickButton1()" />
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Button 2" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Options", "Home")'" />
</div>

<div>
    <canvas id="mapCanvas" width="500" height="150" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
function ClickButton1() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ClickButton1", "Definition")',
        async: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: function () {
            return "error";
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

My CONTROLLER

```html
namespace Traveler.Controllers
{
    public class DefinitionController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // Action click on Button 1
        public void ClickButton1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Button 1 Clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `ClickButton1` marked as `HttpPost`? Nope. But your JavaScript is trying to POST to it. Why are you doing `return "error";` instead of getting the error message? Did you bother looking at the browser's developer tools at the network traffic?

Comment: Hi Mason, used the code from this post for another dev who seemed to have the same pb. Am surely missing something. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928088/how-to-use-buttons-in-asp-net-to-call-a-method

Comment: I pointed out what you missed in my previous comment.

Comment: Did I miss that I have to mark the button as 'httpPost'? Not sure how to get the error message.

Comment: I said ClickButton1 and HttpPost. That doesn't mean your button. That means your action method. By default, action methods have GET requests routed to them, not POST requests. So in order for it to receive a GET request, you must add an `[HttpPost]` attribute to `ClickButton1`. You would probably see an error message to this effect if you used your browser's developer tools to watch the network traffic. I suggest you learn how to do this, because seeing exactly the response from the server is something you need to know how to do.

Comment: Understand better now, many thx @Mason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the input type to button from submit to avoid multiple submit.

Mark you Controllers method as `[HttpPost]` and try again.

If you are wondering why should you do that, read this:

The `[HttpPost]` attribute tells the routing engine to send any POST requests to that action method to the one method over the other. This is a type of overloading.

If you are wondering how to mark you Method as a `[HttpPost]` method, look at this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void ClickButton1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Button 1 Clicked");
}
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thank you this seems to work indeed. the debugger now stops at the Console. Cannot see the text in the console but at least it gets to that point. Many thanks !

Comment: @Frens You are welcome my friend, if this answer was helpful to you please vote up :)

Comment: I did vote up...am too new on the forum yet to have this counted though. I checked your answer as a valid one to the issue. Cheers !